# Vue 3 component not rendering on the page

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js, pagination

I have this Vue 3 Pagination component where I'm getting data from Laravel 10.

```
<Pagination :links="products.data.links" class="mt-6" />
```

On the browser I can see this component when I inspect elements, but, nothing really comes on the browser visually. The component basically meant to display the pagination links with the HTML generated.

[image]

My `Pagination.vue` as follows:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    links: Object
  }
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <Component
        :is="link.url ? 'Link' : 'span'"
        v-for="link in links"
        :href="link.url"
        :html="link.label"
        class="px-1"
        :class="{ 'text-gray-500': ! link.url, 'font-bold' : link.active }"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

Just FYI the Laravel index() function to generate the data as follows:

```
    public function index(): JsonResponse
    {
        $products = Product::paginate(4);
        return response()->json($products);
    }
```

The JSON generated by the Laravel code can be found [here](http://jsonblob.com/1221475579911331840)

Anyone got any idea why this is not rendering the elements on the page ?. Thanks.

Comment: It's <a> and not <link>. If Link is supposed to be a component then this should be explicitly stated and properly implemented

Comment: ^Yeah, did you ensure that `Link` is a globally registered component name? If it isn't using `<component is="Link">` will not resolve to any component but a html-tag called `<link>` which isn't a valid tag (links are usually `<a>` tags).

Otherwise, as mentioned, explicitly import and pass the `Link` component to `<component>`

```
<script setup>
import Link from './Link.vue'
</script>

<template>
   <component :is="Link">
```